# What default permissions does default service account have?

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I set up a fresh Kubernetes cluster. I assume the both `kube-system` and `default` namespaces will get a service account named `default`? Which permissions does that service account have? Full read/write permissions?

I'm essentially asking this to understand best practises to give a custom Go controller write access to resources.

Answer (score 4):

Service accounts have no inherent permissions. The permissions they have depend entirely on the authorization mode configured (`--authorization-mode` flag passed to the apiserver)

Defining RBAC roles is a good method for specifying the permissions required for a controller.

There are existing role definitions for in-tree controllers at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac/bootstrappolicy